# How to mock an async repository with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a unit test for a class that calls into an async repository.  I'm using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.  My generic repository looks like this.

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly SaasDispatcherDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public EntityRepository(SaasDispatcherDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Then I have a service class that calls FindBy and FirstOrDefaultAsync on an instance of the repository:

```
    public async Task<Uri> GetCompanyProductURLAsync(Guid externalCompanyID, string productCode, Guid loginToken)
    {            
        CompanyProductUrl companyProductUrl = await _Repository.FindBy(u => u.Company.ExternalCompanyID == externalCompanyID && u.Product.Code == productCode.Trim()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (companyProductUrl == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var builder = new UriBuilder(companyProductUrl.Url);
        builder.Query = $"-s{loginToken.ToString()}";

        return builder.Uri;
    }
```

I'm trying to mock the repository call in my test below:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCompanyProductURLAsync_ReturnsNullForInvalidCompanyProduct()
    {
        var companyProducts = Enumerable.Empty<CompanyProductUrl>().AsQueryable();

        var mockRepository = new Mock<IEntityRepository<CompanyProductUrl>>();
        mockRepository.Setup(r => r.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<CompanyProductUrl, bool>>>())).Returns(companyProducts);

        var service = new CompanyProductService(mockRepository.Object);

        var result = await service.GetCompanyProductURLAsync(Guid.NewGuid(), "wot", Guid.NewGuid());

        Assert.Null(result);
    }
```

However, when the test executes the call to the repository, I get the following error:

```
The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

How can I properly mock the repository to get this to work?

Comment: May be this can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx

Comment: Read the section on `Testing with async queries`

Comment: You need to mock both `IQueryable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerableAccessor<T>` interfaces as well

Comment: For a simple, concise answer using In-memory database, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74963281/8644294

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Thanks to @Nkosi for pointing me to a link with an example of doing the same thing in EF 6: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx.  This didn't work exactly as-is with EF Core, but I was able to start with it and make modifications to get it working.  Below are the test classes that I created to "mock" IAsyncQueryProvider:

```
internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
    }
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    { }

    public TestAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression)
    { }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); }
    }
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _inner.Current;
        }
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

And here is my updated test case that uses these classes:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetCompanyProductURLAsync_ReturnsNullForInvalidCompanyProduct()
{
    var companyProducts = Enumerable.Empty<CompanyProductUrl>().AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<CompanyProductUrl>>();

    mockSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<CompanyProductUrl>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(new TestAsyncEnumerator<CompanyProductUrl>(companyProducts.GetEnumerator()));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<CompanyProductUrl>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<CompanyProductUrl>(companyProducts.Provider));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<CompanyProductUrl>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(companyProducts.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<CompanyProductUrl>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(companyProducts.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<CompanyProductUrl>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => companyProducts.GetEnumerator());

    var contextOptions = new DbContextOptions<SaasDispatcherDbContext>();
    var mockContext = new Mock<SaasDispatcherDbContext>(contextOptions);
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<CompanyProductUrl>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var entityRepository = new EntityRepository<CompanyProductUrl>(mockContext.Object);

    var service = new CompanyProductService(entityRepository);

    var result = await service.GetCompanyProductURLAsync(Guid.NewGuid(), "wot", Guid.NewGuid());

    Assert.Null(result);
}
```

Comment: Glad you eventually figured it out. I was digging in the source code on github to see if they had any moq examples. Funny enough I was investigating one when I check and saw that you came to your own solution. Cool.

Comment: I would convert that to an extension method so you can reuse it in your tests.

Comment: Check answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40500030/5233410) which references this answer where the extension method was used. Happy coding!!!

Comment: Thanks again, @Nkosi!

Comment: Works great, thanks! Perhaps you can add the following extension to your answer too?

`public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> TestAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            return new TestAsyncEnumerable<T>(source);
        }
    }`

Comment: This helped out a bunch after trying to implement EF Mocking in core and not realising they'd changed the IDbAsyncQueryProvider etc. Thanks.

Comment: How does `TestAsyncEnumerable<T>` get the inner (source) enumeration when just it is returned from  `ExecuteAsync` with expression as its constructor argument? I'm sure it get empty enumeration, doesn't?

Comment: Can you give same example for Insert and Update record?

Comment: Would you be willing to update this to core 3.0?  I can't get passed "Argument expression is not valid" on _inner.Execute<TResults>(expression)

Comment: @BillRob Were you ever able to solve the updated to Core 3.0? I'm updating something right now to 3.1 and running into the same issue.

Comment: @NapoleonIkeJones I was not able to get around it.  I ended up using InMemory EF database and randomly generated a new seed for each test execution.

Comment: @BillRob and anybody else, I've found a work around for BillRob issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888111/how-to-remove-my-variable-to-tresult-casting-method

Comment: @Mandelbrotter do you have an updated link? The one you used 404s.

Comment: @Spencer Stream No I do not. Seems I can't write a good post so I deleted it. I'll post the solution in this comment just give me a few moments to get it.

Comment: public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
  object returnValue = Execute(expression);
  return ConvertToThreadingTResult<TResult>(returnValue);
}

Comment: TResult IAsyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var returnValue = ExecuteAsync<TResult>(expression, default);
            return ConvertToTResult<TResult>(returnValue);
        }

Comment: private static TR ConvertToTResult <TR>(dynamic toConvert)
        {
            return (TR)toConvert;
        }

Comment: private static TR ConvertToThreadingTResult<TR>(dynamic toConvert)
        {
            return (TR)Task.FromResult(toConvert);
        }

Comment: IAsyncEnumerable does not contain GetEnumerator, only GetAsyncEnumerator in .NET 5.0. None of these solutions work for .NET 5.0

Comment: @Mandelbrotter Your solution helped me a great deal, but I almost didn't see it in the comments. I'm goin go to attempt to post an answer, but most of it was based on your follow up help, so thank you!

Comment: For .NET Core 3.1 @Mandelbrotter 's fix can be replaced by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314109/98422

Answer (score 83):

Try to use my Moq/NSubstitute/FakeItEasy extension [MockQueryable](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable):
supported all Sync/Async operations (see more examples [here](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/tree/master/src/MockQueryable/MockQueryable.Sample))

```
//1 - create a List<T> with test items
var users = new List<UserEntity>()
{
 new UserEntity,
 ...
};

//2 - build mock by extension
var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMock();

//3 - setup the mock as Queryable for Moq
_userRepository.Setup(x => x.GetQueryable()).Returns(mock.Object);

//3 - setup the mock as Queryable for NSubstitute
_userRepository.GetQueryable().Returns(mock);
```

DbSet also supported

```
//2 - build mock by extension
var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();

//3 - setup DbSet for Moq
var userRepository = new TestDbSetRepository(mock.Object);

//3 - setup DbSet for NSubstitute
var userRepository = new TestDbSetRepository(mock);
```

**Notes:**

- AutoMapper is also supported from 1.0.4 ver
- DbQuery supported from 1.1.0 ver
- EF Core 3.0 supported from 3.0.0 ver
- .Net 5 [supported](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq/5.0.0) from 5.0.0  ver

Comment: This seems to be a really nice package to use instead of writing a bunch of double implementation for a fake `IAsyncQueryProvider` etc.

Comment: This is a great package, which did the trick right away. Thanks!

Comment: @Noob try to open link from my comment, or just take a look https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/blob/master/src/MockQueryable/MockQueryable.Sample/MyServiceMoqTests.cs

Comment: @Noob in MyService.CreateUserIfNotExist I use FirstOrDefaultAsync, and here you can see  tests for CreateUserIfNotExist logic https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/blob/master/src/MockQueryable/MockQueryable.Sample/MyServiceMoqTests.cs

Comment: Since .NET 5 I'm getting "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'." when using MockQueryable.Moq.

Comment: @Valuator .net 5 supported https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq/5.0.0

Answer (score 10):

Much less code solution. Use the in-memory db context which should take care of bootstrapping all the sets for you. You no longer need to mock out the DbSet on your context but if you want to return data from a service for example, you can simply return the actual set data of the in-memory context.

```
DbContextOptions< SaasDispatcherDbContext > options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder< SaasDispatcherDbContext >()
  .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
  .Options;

  _db = new SaasDispatcherDbContext(optionsBuilder: options);
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Why not? Add a reference to the in-memory nuget package to get the UseInMemoryDatabase extension method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: Would this not be a form of integration test? I know it is an in-memory database, but you will be testing against a system which is what integration tests are. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Integration tests should test systems which are integrated with each other. Since you are not leaving the context of the original system, or rather "mock" the external system by replacing it with the in-memory-mock system, you are not really leaving the unittest-context.

Answer (score 7):

I had some problems with the approved solution. Apparently, there were changes starting with Entity Framework 5.0.3.  The IAsyncQueryProvider, IAsyncEnumerable and IAsyncEnumerator have different methods one must implement.   I found [an article online that provides a solution](https://jason-ge.medium.com/mock-async-data-repository-in-asp-net-core-3-1-634cb19a3013).  This works for my .NET 6 application.  Be sure to include the `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query` statement.  For me, Visual Studio was having trouble finding the three interfaces and wanted me to create them manually.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace MyApp.Tests
{
    internal class AsyncHelper
    {
        internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IAsyncQueryProvider
        {
            private readonly IQueryProvider _innerQueryProvider;

            internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
            {
                _innerQueryProvider = inner;
            }

            public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
            {
                return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
            }

            public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
            {
                return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
            }

            public object Execute(Expression expression) => _innerQueryProvider.Execute(expression);

            public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => _innerQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);

            TResult IAsyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                Type expectedResultType = typeof(TResult).GetGenericArguments()[0];
                object? executionResult = ((IQueryProvider)this).Execute(expression);

                return (TResult)typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult))
                    .MakeGenericMethod(expectedResultType)
                    .Invoke(null, new[] { executionResult });
            }
        }

        internal class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
        {
            public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
                : base(enumerable)
            { }

            public TestAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
                : base(expression)
            { }

            IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this);

            public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
                => new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
        }

        internal class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
        {
            private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

            public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
            {
                _enumerator = inner;
            }

            public T Current => _enumerator.Current;

            public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => new(Task.Run(() => _enumerator.Dispose()));

            public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() => new(_enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

After creating this AsyncHelper, I was able to mock my database context.

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> myList = new List<MyEntity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id= 6,
                FirstName = "John",
                MidName = "Q",
                LastName = "Doe",
            }
        }.AsQueryable();


        Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>> dbSetMock = new();

        dbSetMock.As<IAsyncEnumerable<MyEntity>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator(default))
            .Returns(new AsyncHelper.TestAsyncEnumerator<MyEntity>(myList.GetEnumerator()));

        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>()
            .Setup(m => m.Provider)
            .Returns(new AsyncHelper.TestAsyncQueryProvider<MyEntity>(myList.Provider));

        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression)
            .Returns(myList.Expression);

        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType)
            .Returns(myList.ElementType);

        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(() => myList.GetEnumerator());

Mock<MyDbContext> mockContext = new();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.People).Returns(dbSetMock().Object);
```

Then, I arrange my unit test with my mock context.

```
        MyRepository myRepository = new(mockContext.Object);
        Person? person = await myRepository.GetPersonById(6);
```

Now, I can Assert any conditions without issue.

```
Assert.NotNull(person);
Assert.True(person.Id == 6);
Assert.True(person.FirstName == "John");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton; this solved the DbSetMock for me and reduced considerably all the suggestions and innacurate implementations that I was finding.

Answer (score 3):

I'm maintaining two open-source projects that do the heavy lifting of setting up the mocks and actually emulates `SaveChanges(Async)`.

For EF Core: https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock

For EF6: https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-mock

Both projects have Nuget packages with integration for Moq or NSubstitute.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I found a nuget package to do this.

[MockQueryable](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/blob/master/src/MockQueryable/MockQueryable.Sample/MyServiceMoqTests.cs)
and
[MockQueryable.Moq](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable)

This does all of the work for you.

```
[TestCase("AnyFirstName", "AnyExistLastName", "01/20/2012", "Users with DateOfBirth more than limit")]
    [TestCase("ExistFirstName", "AnyExistLastName", "02/20/2012", "User with FirstName already exist")]
    [TestCase("AnyFirstName", "ExistLastName", "01/20/2012", "User already exist")]
    public void CreateUserIfNotExist(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth, string expectedError)
    {
      //arrange
      var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
      var service = new MyService(userRepository.Object);
      var users = new List<UserEntity>
      {
        new UserEntity {LastName = "ExistLastName", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/20/2012", UsCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat)},
        new UserEntity {FirstName = "ExistFirstName"},
        new UserEntity {DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/20/2012", UsCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat)},
        new UserEntity {DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/20/2012", UsCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat)},
        new UserEntity {DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/20/2012", UsCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat)}
      };
      //expect
      var mock = users.BuildMock();
      userRepository.Setup(x => x.GetQueryable()).Returns(mock);
      //act
      var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<ApplicationException>(() =>
        service.CreateUserIfNotExist(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth));
      //assert
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedError, ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a port of the accepted answer to F#, I just did it for myself and thought it may save someone the time. I have also updated the example to match the updated C#8 IAsyncEnumarable API and tweaked the Mock setup to be generic.

```
    type TestAsyncEnumerator<'T> (inner : IEnumerator<'T> ) =     

        let inner : IEnumerator<'T> = inner

        interface IAsyncEnumerator<'T> with
            member this.Current with get() = inner.Current
            member this.MoveNextAsync () = ValueTask<bool>(Task.FromResult(inner.MoveNext()))
            member this.DisposeAsync () = ValueTask(Task.FromResult(inner.Dispose))

    type TestAsyncEnumerable<'T> =       
        inherit EnumerableQuery<'T>

        new (enumerable : IEnumerable<'T>) = 
            { inherit EnumerableQuery<'T> (enumerable) }
        new (expression : Expression) = 
            { inherit EnumerableQuery<'T> (expression) }

        interface IAsyncEnumerable<'T> with
            member this.GetAsyncEnumerator cancellationToken : IAsyncEnumerator<'T> =
                 new TestAsyncEnumerator<'T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
                 :> IAsyncEnumerator<'T>

        interface IQueryable<'T> with
            member this.Provider with get() = new TestAsyncQueryProvider<'T>(this) :> IQueryProvider

    and 
        TestAsyncQueryProvider<'TEntity> 
        (inner : IQueryProvider) =       

        let inner : IQueryProvider = inner

        interface IAsyncQueryProvider with

            member this.Execute (expression : Expression) =
                inner.Execute expression

            member this.Execute<'TResult> (expression : Expression) =
                inner.Execute<'TResult> expression

            member this.ExecuteAsync<'TResult> ((expression : Expression), cancellationToken) =
                inner.Execute<'TResult> expression

            member this.CreateQuery (expression : Expression) =
                new TestAsyncEnumerable<'TEntity>(expression) :> IQueryable

            member this.CreateQuery<'TElement> (expression : Expression) =
                new TestAsyncEnumerable<'TElement>(expression) :> IQueryable<'TElement>


    let getQueryableMockDbSet<'T when 'T : not struct>
        (sourceList : 'T seq) : Mock<DbSet<'T>> =

        let queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

        let dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<'T>>()

        dbSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<'T>>()
            .Setup(fun m -> m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(TestAsyncEnumerator<'T>(queryable.GetEnumerator())) |> ignore

        dbSet.As<IQueryable<'T>>()
            .SetupGet(fun m -> m.Provider)
            .Returns(TestAsyncQueryProvider<'T>(queryable.Provider)) |> ignore

        dbSet.As<IQueryable<'T>>().Setup(fun m -> m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression) |> ignore
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<'T>>().Setup(fun m -> m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType) |> ignore
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<'T>>().Setup(fun m -> m.GetEnumerator ()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator ()) |> ignore
        dbSet
```

Comment: You may want to ask a new question that refers to F# and answer with one. It does not belong to here.

Comment: The question does not mention the language. I also improved upon the accepted answer by adhering to the latest API. I don't think that deserves a markdown as it is useful. I am adding extra information for .Net programmers who land here.

Comment: It contains C# tag

Comment: Either way man, I am not hurting anyone or clouding the topic, I am adding more useful information that is related directly to the question. I think you have been unfair but that is your perogative I guess.

Answer (score 2):

A way simpler approach is to write your own `ToListAsync` in one of the core layers. You dont need any concrete class implementation. Something like:

```
    public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        if (queryable is EnumerableQuery)
        {
            return queryable.ToList();
        }

        return await QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(queryable);
    }
```

This also has the added benefit that you could use ToListAsync from anywhere in your app without needing to drag EF references all along.

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging @Jed Veatch's accepted answer, as well as the comments provided by @Mandelbrotter, the following solution works for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5. This will resolve the "Argument expression is not valid" exception that arises from working with the above code in later .NET versions.

TL;DR - Complete EnumerableExtensions.cs code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Usualdosage/a1717f776b593d177e410d40cc23bdd9).

Usage:

```
public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableAsyncMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
{
    var mockAsyncDbSet = sourceList.ToAsyncDbSetMock<T>();
    var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
    mockAsyncDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockAsyncDbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));
    return mockAsyncDbSet.Object;
}
```

Then, using [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq) and [Autofixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture), you can do:

```
var myMockData = Fixture.CreateMany<MyMockEntity>();
MyDatabaseContext.SetupGet(x => x.MyDBSet).Returns(GetQueryableAsyncMockDbSet(myMockData));
```

Comment: Here's EnumerableExtensions.cs with a fix for when an FirstOrDefaultAsync or similar method returns NULL:

https://adm.ski/enumerableextensions

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who stuck at mocking `DbContext` with async queries, `IAsyncQueryProvider` and other things. Heres example usage of copy-paste types for netcore3.1 and higher. Based on generic DbContextCreation and generic DbSet seed.

```cs
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MockDbContextAsynced<TDbContext>
    {
        private readonly TDbContext _mock;
        public TDbContext Object => _mock;

        public MockDbContextAsynced()
        {
            _mock = Activator.CreateInstance<TDbContext>();
        }
          // suppressed. see full code in source below
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var testData = new List<MyEntity>
        {
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
        };

        var mockDbContext = new MockDbContextAsynced<MyDbContext>();
        mockDbContext.AddDbSetData<MyEntity>(testData.AsQueryable());

        mockDbContext.MyEntities.ToArrayAsync();
        // or
        mockDbContext.MyEntities.SingleAsync();
        // or etc.
        
        // To inject MyDbContext as type parameter with mocked data
        var mockService = new SomeService(mockDbContext.Object);
    }
```

For full implemented types see this source: https://gist.github.com/Zefirrat/a04658c827ba3ebffe03fda48d53ea11

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by 3xguy worked for me.
I installed https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable for moq.
Then i adjusted it to work with what i needed. Here's a sample of that worked for me.

```
using MockQueryable.Moq;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
namespace MOQ.Tests
{
    public class MockQueryableExample
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestMockQueryable()
        {
            // Arrange
            var repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepositoryInterface>();
            var contextMock = new Mock<IDbContextInterface>();
            var data = new List<DataEntity>
            {
                new DataEntity
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Item 1",
                    Value = 10
                },
                new DataEntity
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Item 2",
                    Value = 20
                },
                new DataEntity
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Item 3",
                    Value = 30
                }
            };
            // Create a mock DbSet
            var mockSet = data.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
            // Create a mock context
            var context = contextMock.Object;
            contextMock.Setup(c => c.Entities).Returns(mockSet.Object);
            // Create the repository with the mock context
            var repository = new RepositoryClass(context);
            // Act
            var result = await repository.GetAllAsync();
            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }
    }
}
```