# Create unit test for View() with a List in ASP.net core MVC application

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

I am new in unit testing. I have a controller - `StudentsController` with dependency injection and there my `Index()` method:

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    public readonly UniversityContext _context;//Database
    public StudentsController(UniversityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }//Constructor with database
    // GET: Students
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Students.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Next i need to write a correct unit test code, that check, if:

> 1) a View() have a list with my students
>
> 2) The query with students is not null.

I read about Mock objects, but I don't know how to write the correct code. My code that I wrote so far:

```
public class StudentsControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Index_ReturnsAViewResult_WithAListOfStudents()
    {
        var mockRepo = new Mock<UniversityContext>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Students.ToList()).Returns(GetTestStudents());//There i get following error:Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object
        var controller = new StudentsController(mockRepo.Object);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        //// Assert
        var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
        var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Student>>(
            viewResult.ViewData.Model);
        Assert.NotNull(model);//Second Condition

    }
    public List<Student> GetTestStudents()
    {
        var sessions = new List<Student>();
        sessions.Add(new Student()
        {
            bDate = new DateTime(1994, 7, 2),
            Name = "Test One"
        });
        sessions.Add(new Student()
        {
            bDate = new DateTime(1995, 7, 1),
            Name = "Test Two"
        });
        return sessions;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me, how to correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to mock the members of the context, which in this case is the `.Students` property. `ToList` is an extension method being call on the property and cannot be mocked by moq.

Also `.Students` is a DbSet and would need to be mocked as well.

Using the test classes from this answer :

[How to mock an async repository with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491640/5233410)

The following generic extension methods were derived

```
public static class MockDbSetExtensions {
    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> AsDbSetMock<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class {
        IQueryable<T> queryableList = list.AsQueryable();
        Mock<DbSet<T>> dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(queryableList.Provider);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(queryableList.Expression);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(queryableList.ElementType);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryableList.GetEnumerator());
        return dbSetMock;
    }

    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> ToAsyncDbSetMock<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class {        
        var data = source.AsQueryable();        
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();        
        mockSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));        
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(data.Provider));        
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());        
        return mockSet;
    }

}
```

With the above utilities, update

```
 mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Students.ToList()).Returns(GetTestStudents());
```

To

```
var studentsMockedDbSet = GetTestStudents().ToAsyncDbSetMock();
mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Students).Returns(studentsMockedDbSet.Object);
```

Comment: There is a problem. "Cannot convert from List<Student> to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Student>"

Comment: @Eldar you are correct I made a mistake. updating answer now

Comment: @Eldar that `ToListAsync` is also goin to cause you some trouble.

Comment: Now i getting the following error: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: repo => repo.Students

Comment: @Eldar Check your DbContext and make sure that Students property is `virtual`

Comment: That work, but in test explorer i see following message: Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult
Actual:   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 How can i fix that? Thanks

Comment: @Eldar that is what I was referring to about the async call. check updated answer. Add the suggested reusable utilities to help with mocking EF in your tests.

Comment: Well, thanks for that, now i read about how to mock an async method with EF.

Comment: @Eldar I included a link in the answer to help with that

Comment: I did not handle it. Can you help me with that error? I paste that async methods, but dont know how to use it.

Comment: When i change my StudentsController Index() method to the non-async, it perfectly works. But async...