# How can I do Task.FromResult<T> when I don't know T at compile time (but I do have a reference to the Type)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, .net-core-3.1

## Summary

Given a *run-time* reference to a type (and a value of that type), how can I create a completed `Task` of that type with the given value?

Similar to `Task.FromResult<T>(value)`, but where `T` is unknown at compile time?

---

## Background

Not that it matters, I'm trying to create a mock implementation of `IAsyncQueryProvider`, by adapting some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491640/98422) (including some changes for .NET Core 3.1 suggested in the comments by @Mandelbrotter).

Here's the relevant method:

```
public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var value = Execute(expression);

    return Task.FromResult((dynamic) value);
}
```

Note that because this is an async method, `TResult` is actually always of type `Task<something>`. But, we can't declare the method like that because we're implementing a pre-defined interface. Nonetheless, we use `Task.FromResult()` to return a completed `Task`.

You'll notice that we don't use `Task.FromResult(value)` directly; we cast `value` to `dynamic` first. This is because the return value of the `Execute` call is declared as `Object`, and if we simply did `Task.FromResult(value)` we'd return something of type `Task<Object>`, which is generally not the correct type - and that causes issues further up the stack.

However, while this approach works for queries returning simple types such as `int` or `DateTime`, it fails when the query returns a nullable value. In this case, when the value returned is not null the type of `value` is just the underlying type, not the nullable type - and so we end up returning something of type `Task<int>` instead of `Task<int?>`.

I'd like to solve this (and do away with the use of `dynamic`) by explicitly creating a `Task` of the correct type. I *can* determine the desired type, either using reflection on `TResult`, or more conveniently by using `expression.Type`.

However, even once I know the type, I can't find a way to create a completed `Task` of that type. `Task.FromResult<T>` requires me to know `T` at compile-time. I've not been able to find a way to create a completed `Task` by passing in the type as a parameter.

Comment: You'd be way better off redesigning the method so that it returns `Task<TResult>` and the caller provides a type that *isn't* a task, but rather what the result of that task is.  As it is, you've written code that will just fail at runtime if the caller doesn't just happen to know that they need to provide `Task<T>` as the generic argument, and you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Servy I think he's trying to mock for the sake of tests

Comment: @galdin The method is called `ExecuteAsync` it sure does seem like it's inherent to the method that it's returning a task, and it's not specific to just the mock object.  The thing that he's basing his design off of has a signature altered in the way I described, so if anything this is likely an unacceptable deviation for the mock version to make.

Comment: @Servy, @galdin: I cannot change the signature of the method, because I'm implementing an interface (`IAsyncQueryProvider`) whose method signatures I cannot change. Anyway, see my updated - I've found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy: since I could no longer post an answer (this having been marked as duplicate), I added my solution to the question, on behalf of all those people who might be trying to do the same thing. You've reverted my changes to the question, and so those changes are lost. I mention that so that anyone looking for the answer knows who to thank.

Comment: @GaryMcGill There's no need to edit the question to say that the duplicate answers the question or to copy the answer from the duplicate.  People who want to find the answer can simply go to the duplicate.  That's the whole point of closing questions as a duplicate.  But I'm glad that the answer I proved for you want helpful for you solving your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this because this question is more specific than the marked duplicate.

Comment: @galdin Thank God that you can view the edit history of the question. And thank you for writing that you put the answer in the question! Your solution fixes my problem 100%. The question which is marked as duplicated is wrong. It is not the same.

Answer (score -2):

Since `Execute()` returns an `object`, something like this should work as long as it can actually be cast to `TResult`:

```cs
public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var value = Execute(expression); 
    if(value is TResult valueT) return Task.FromResult(valueT); // works for nullable types
    return Task.FromResult((T) value); // non-nullable types
}
```

The linked answer has a `Execute<T>()` example... if you choose to use that, you'd get something like:

```cs
public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var value = Execute<TResult>(expression);
    return Task.FromResult(value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no - `TResult` is something like `Task<int?>` and `Execute` in this case would return an `int?` (except that in fact we'd get the unboxed value so it would just be `int`).