# blazor mocking IDbContextFactory

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, blazor

I'm trying to unit test my server API for a Blazor projet

So I have this constructor for my API which receive a factory

```
public MyThingApi(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
```

Then I have this function to get a list of my things:

```
public async Task<List<MyThing>> GetMyThingsAsync()
    {
        using var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
        return await context.MyThings.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Now, if I want to test GetMyThingsAsync, using Moq, I would have to mock the factory. But the mock code would look like:

```
Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>
```

And that's what I don't understand: MyDbContext is not an interface. So in the code CreateDbContext will always return a MyDbContext. So I cannot mock it, it will be the "real" context with a "real" database connection. So context.MyThings will retrieve it from the database.

So what is the magic to mock the context when it is generated by a factory?

Comment: DBContext and IDbContextFactory are not easy to Mock.  There are a few posts around, but none do a good job.  I've tried and failed!  I use the DBContext InMemory option.  but it's a bit difficult to configure.

Comment: Create a DbContext broker and mock that.

Comment: do you have any references on how to do a dbcontext broker ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses In-memory database which makes the whole mocking quite simple.

### Step 1:

Install these nuget packages in your Unit Test project:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
2. Moq
3. xunit
4. Shouldly

### Step 2:

Setup the test like so:

```cs
using Moq;
using Shouldly;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace YourProject.UnitTests;

public class YourTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Get_My_ThingsAsync()
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var mockDbFactory = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "SomeDatabaseInMemory")
                            .Options;

        // Insert seed data into the database using an instance of the context
        using (var context = new MyDbContext(options))
        {
            context.MyThings.Add(new MyThing { Id = 1, SomeProp = "Some Prop Value" });
            context.MyThings.Add(new MyThing { Id = 2, SomeProp = "Some Prop Value" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Now the in-memory db already has data, we don't have to seed everytime the factory returns the new DbContext:
        mockDbFactory.Setup(f => f.CreateDbContextAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(() => new MyDbContext(options));

        // ACT
        var myThingApi = new MyThingApi(mockDbFactory.Object);
        var result = await myThingApi.GetMyThingsAsync();

        // ASSERT
        result.ShouldNotBeNull();
        result.Count.ShouldBe(2);
        // other asserts
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a in memory sqlite database for testing.