# The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to mock some DB access code using simple lists. It generally works except for Async. which causes the error saying the provider does not support Iqueriable. I tries a few suggested solutions but they seem to cause an expression error when executing the linq query

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestAsyncFromList()
{
    
    List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    var queryable = items.AsQueryable();
    var totalSync = queryable.Count();
    var totalAsync = await queryable.CountAsync(); // The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'
    Assert.True(totalSync==totalAsync);
}
```

I was expecting that there is an 'AsAsyncQueiable' solution
Tried this [The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023223/the-provider-for-the-source-iqueryable-doesnt-implement-iasyncqueryprovider) - but got Expression error

I was after a general solution  - not something that uses  EF in memory or SQLlite In memory  ( Although these do work for testing ).   It turns out that the actual solution was to use MockQueryable.Moq; BUT that wont work for value types - they must be Ref types

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to test EF6 code or EFCore code or something else?

Comment: As the message says [...]Async only works if the underlying provider supports it. List does not. And there is really no need to us async here.

Comment: Yes  @igor- I was originally trying to mock EFCORE for testing - I have a workaround by using SQL lite in memory - but I'd still like to understand how to solve this problem - it just seems simple.

Comment: @marsze I get its not supported but ideally I would have hoped the Asynchronous methods would use synchronous ones as a fall back.  The code is an example to show the problem  - the original purpose was testing - its not actually being used like the above case

Comment: See the marked duplicate. The answer illustrates how to mock your DbContext and DbSet instances for EFCore which uses an InMemory instance of the DbContext.

Comment: Thanks @Igor - I do already use SQLLITE in memory - but for various reasons I also need plain old objects that can be saved to JSON eg something that is NOT EF core.   Anyway I did find a solution in the article you referred to  - which is to use MockQueryable.Moq   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71994567/how-to-moq-setup-for-await-with-tolistasync-variable-which-is-already-queried-as]   - the only problem is that it wont work for value types (eg like a list of ints as above )  - This is ok am able to use a list of ref types - so thanks for pointing me in the right direction