How to write unit test to async method of controller with EF Core
I'm trying to create a unit test for an asynchronous method of controller with adding pagination. Data is injected with DI and requested by using a repository pattern from the context class.
Code of context class:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace Project.Models;
public class ProjectDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectDBContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectDBContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
}

Code of interface of repository:
namespace Project.Models;

public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product>? Products { get; }
}

Code of implementing of repository interface:
namespace Project.Models;
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private ProjectDBContext context;
    public EFProductRepository(ProjectDBContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }
    public IQueryable<Product> Products => context.Products;
}

Code of controller class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using Project.ViewModels;
namespace Project.Controllers;
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;
    public int pageSize = 2;
    public ProductController(IProductRepository _productRepository)
    {
        productRepository = _productRepository;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductList(int page = 1)
    {
        IQueryable<Product>? productSource = productRepository.Products;
        int produtCount = await productSource!.CountAsync(); 
        List<Product> pageProducts = await productSource!.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        PageViewModel pageViewModel = new(page, pageSize, produtCount);
        ProductListViewModel productListViewModel = new()
        {
            PageViewModel = pageViewModel,
            Products = pageProducts
        };
        return View(productListViewModel);
    }
}

Code of unit test:
    [Fact]
    public void Can_Use_Repository()
    {
        //Arrange
        Product[] productsTestData = new Product[]
        {
            new Product{ProductID=1,ProductName="P1"},
            new Product{ProductID=2,ProductName="P2"}
        };
        Mock<IProductRepository> mockRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        mockRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Products).Returns(productsTestData.AsQueryable<Product>());
        ProductController productController = new ProductController(mockRepository.Object);
        //Act
        var resultProducts = (productController.ProductList()?.Result as ProductListViewModel ?? new())?.Products?.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<Product>();
        //Assert
        Assert.True(resultProducts.Length == 2);
        Assert.Equal("P1", resultProducts[0].ProductName);
        Assert.Equal(1, resultProducts[0].ProductID);
        Assert.Equal("P2", resultProducts[1].ProductName);
        Assert.Equal(2, resultProducts[1].ProductID);
    }

So when I run a test I get an error: "The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations."
Tried a synchronous variant of the method in the controller and the test ran succesful. Found some close-by theme questions on stackoverflow(Example: How to mock an async repository with Entity Framework Core - If I am right, in this question not using repository pattern and data mocking directly from context), but can`t change the code from there to my case.

This question is similar to: How to mock an async repository with Entity Framework Core. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes i read this question. And if I right, in this question not using repository pattern and data mocking directly from context. Try to use code, but can`t change to my case.

so this won't work for you? mockRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Products).Returns(productsTestData.AsQueryable<Product>()); adding the BuildMock from the library after AsQueryable?

I`m trying to find solution without third party libraries, because i want to understand how it works with standart (ASP .Net Core+EF Core).

look at the first answer then...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491640/23871731 this?If yes- i have looked on this answer? and try to use code in my case, but it don`t work. If no, please be more accurate and specific.

this answer from the same quesiton seems to be the most up-to-date

Thank you for you patience. Can you expalin how it works with getting data from repository pattern, not directly, from context?

see my answer..

I use MockQueryable.Core for mocking repositories for async operations. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Core) There is a breaking change in 7.0.2 that I'll likely have a look into since they moved a namespace to make it specific to EFCore, so 7.0.1 doesn't require an additional namespace declaration to work for repositories.
With MockQueryable, your test just needs to be updated with:
[Fact]
public async Task Can_Use_Repository()
{
    //Arrange
    Product[] productsTestData = new Product[]
    {
        new Product{ProductID=1,ProductName="P1"},
        new Product{ProductID=2,ProductName="P2"}
    };
    Mock<IProductRepository> mockRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Products).Returns(productsTestData.BuildMock());
    // ...

And it will work with both synchronous and asynchronous operations.
Edit: Sorry, also to test async code/calls, you also need to make the test Async. Most test frameworks like NUnit and it looks like xUnit will recognize these and apply them correctly. I updated the test method signature. If the controller actions are async then you can call await productController.SomeAsyncAction(...); where that code is using the IQueryable returned by the repository in an awaited async manner and your test will work.

Thank you for precise answer. So make unit tests to async controller methods with using only asp .net core+ef core in my case is impossible?

Yes, though I also missed one edit to the test code declaration itself. If the controller under test is going to make an awaited async call, the test itself should be async as well. I updated the example.

@StevePy OP is asking if it can be done without the library, which obviously it can...

Since you need a detailed explanation and in all fairness the topic is a bit confusing:
In you repository you return an IQueryable<Product>.
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product>? Products { get; }
}

Then in the controller you consume that repository by getting an IQueryable<Product> before calling the CountAsync extension method
IQueryable<Product>? productSource = productRepository.Products;
int produtCount = await productSource!.CountAsync(); 

You said that it works if it' synchronous, i.e. Count and not CountAsync. This is because the asynchronous extension method is from the EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions class. It forwards internally to a method that makes this check:
if (source.Provider is IAsyncQueryProvider provider)
{
...
}
throw new InvalidOperationException(CoreStrings.IQueryableProviderNotAsync);

If you look back at the exception you'd recognize it's the same.
So the essence of the problem is that the mocked return value IQueryable<Product> from the mocked repository:
Product[] productsTestData = new Product[]
        {
            new Product{ProductID=1,ProductName="P1"},
            new Product{ProductID=2,ProductName="P2"}
        };
Mock<IProductRepository> mockRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
mockRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Products)
.Returns(productsTestData.AsQueryable<Product>()); // this is the issue

returns a concrete implementation of IQueryable<T> whose IQueryProvider is not also an IAsyncQueryProvider.
So the the MockQueryable library and the other answers from the other question try to tackle this problem.
It's irrelevant  whether you have a "repository" or use a "context" directly.
They do so by wrapping the IQueryable<T> in an object that has a provider that not only implements the necessary IQueryProvider but also implements IAsyncQueryProvider.
public interface IAsyncQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Executes the strongly-typed query represented by a specified expression tree asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

This is the simplest example I can think of (not production ready, just for illustration using code from the last answer I linked)
async static Task Main() {
    var simpleList = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };

    var simpleListAsQueryable = simpleList.AsQueryable();
    try {           
        await simpleListAsQueryable.CountAsync();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // The Provider...
    }
    
    var wrapped = new SimpleAsyncQueryable<int>(simpleListAsQueryable);
    var result = await wrapped.CountAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result); // 3
}


class SimpleAsyncQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T> {

    IQueryable<T> _realQueryable;
    IAsyncQueryProvider _asyncQueryProvider;

    public SimpleAsyncQueryable(IQueryable<T> realQueryable) {
        _realQueryable = realQueryable;
        _asyncQueryProvider = new SimpeIAsyncQueryProvider(realQueryable.Provider);
    }
    
    public IQueryProvider Provider => _asyncQueryProvider;
    
    // just forwarding
    public Type ElementType => _realQueryable.ElementType;
    public Expression Expression => _realQueryable.Expression;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _realQueryable.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _realQueryable.GetEnumerator();
}

class SimpeIAsyncQueryProvider : IAsyncQueryProvider {

    IQueryProvider _realQueryProvider;

    public SimpeIAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider queryProvider) {
        _realQueryProvider = queryProvider;
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        Type expectedResultType = typeof(TResult).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        object? executionResult = ((IQueryProvider)this).Execute(expression);

        return (TResult)typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult))
            .MakeGenericMethod(expectedResultType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { executionResult });
    }
    
    // just forwarding
    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) 
        => _realQueryProvider.CreateQuery(expression);
    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        => _realQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);
    public object Execute(Expression expression)
        => _realQueryProvider.Execute(expression);
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        => _realQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);
}


Thank you for such detailed answer. It`s helped me understand a few things about interactions between ef core and moq.

you can accept it...
